# Copy 2nd row from all csv files (8000 files) located in a folder, and save it in new csv file including header

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have 8000 CSV files in a folder. All headers (i.e. 1st row) are same in all CSV files. I want to copy 2nd row of all csv files and paste in a new CSV file, to store in it including the header. New CSV file must be saved in the same folder. Please help using Python language.

I found a python program and it doesn't help much. Please help.

```py
import csv

def load_data(filename)
     mylist = []
     with open(filename) as numbers:
          numbers_data = csv.reder(numbers, delimeter = '_')
          next()
          for row in numbers_data:
               mylist.append(row[1])
          return mylist

new_list = load_data('csv folder path location')
```

Comment: your code copy second column, not row. You would need raterh `first_row = next(numbers_data)`, `second_row = next(numbers_data)` and `mylist.append(second_row)` - without `for`-loop. But you would need `for`-loop with filenames - `for filename in os.listdir(folder):

Comment: do you mean first row directly after header (second row in file) or second row after header  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code copy second column, not row.

You would rather need few `next()` without `for`-loop

```
header     = next(numbers_data) 
second_row = next(numbers_data) 

mylist.append(second_row)
```

But you would need `for`-loop to get filenames and run this function with different files

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
```

---

Full code (but not tested)

```
import csv

def get_second_row(filename)
    with open(filename) as fh:
        reader = csv.reader(fh)

        header     = next(reader)  # first row
        second_row = next(reader)  # second row

        return header, second_row

# --- main ---

folder = '/some/folder/with/csv'

header = None
all_rows = []

for filename in os.listdir(folder)
    if filename.lower().endswith('.csv'):
        full_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        header, row = get_second_row(full_path)
        all_rows.append(row)
    
# ---

with open('output.csv') as fh:
     writer = csv.writer(fh)

     # - write header -
     writer.writerow(header)     # `writerow` without `s` - to write single row

     # - write all rows at once -
     writer.writerows(all_rows)  # `writerows` with `s`   - to write list of rows
```

Comment: Your assumption is not correct Furas, I need first row after header for all csv files. Header must be present at top when we create new csv file.

Comment: Thanks Furas for the program, but its not working for me as I have basic knowledge in Python. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you need first row then use `first_row` instead of `second_row`. And you may return `header` from function and later write this in file.

Comment: I changed code - I removed `first_row` so now `second_row` gives second row in file (first row after header). I also keep header from file and later write it. If something doesn't work then you have to describe details - if you get error then you have to show it, if you get wrong results then you have to show wrong results and expected results. We don't have access to your data, we can't test code - so we only can guess if it will work on your computer.